# NSdate repeating date for upcomming sunday

Tags: nsdate

I am trying to create a date for next Sunday, and make it repeat for every Sunday after.

I know how to create the date using components, and components setWeek is depreciated, so I don't know how to do it now.

Answer (score 0):

if You got the First Sunday Then You Should Do this To repeat it after seven Days!

```
NSString *sunday = @"Here Your Sunday Date";
NSDate *dateSunday = [self dateFromString:sunday];
[self GetNextSunday:dateSunday];
```

Then Call This Method To Get Next Sunday

```
-(void)GetNextSunday:(NSDate*)date
```

{

```
NSDate *NextSunday = [[NSDate alloc]init];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:( NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:date];
components.day = components.day + 8;
NextSunday = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
NSLog(@"%@",NextSunday);
```

}

This Will Return Next 7th Day ! I hope this Will Help You.
for Any Query Comment Below!